# What is the equivalent to the wamp/www folder in ubuntu?

Tags: php, database, android-studio

I understand that most files need to be placed in var/www/html folder.
Most tutorials that show android to database connectivity involve placing php scripts in the wamp/www folder. Where am I supposed to put the php scripts in ubuntu?

Comment: php scripts for what ? I usually put them in /var/www/html/php and I edit the php.ini file to restrict access to /var/www/html and sub directories.

Comment: php scripts to connect to database, php scripts that include POST and GET methods.

Comment: I make a directory and put them in  /var/www/html/php to keep things organized. There really is no standard location, but, if you are using them for web server only I would harden php - see https://tecadmin.net/security-tips-for-lamp-stack-on-linux/# or similar (note restricting php from accessing your system, you would use /var/www/html ) and google harden php.

Comment: Linux equivalent to `WAMP` would be [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)!

Answer (score 1):

You should put them in /var/www/html which is the location on Linux, on Windows it would go in the WAMP directory.

If you prefer you can put them in a different folder, but you'll need to change configurations or use a different URL to do that.

Comment: So all scripts should be put in there and it would work? Can I follow the tutorials that use wamp for database connectivity? (I'm assuming putting the php scripts in var/www/html is the only change I'll have to make)

Comment: Assuming the scripts just use PHP, it'll work just the same, if they run commands you may need to change them, and if you use the rest of the WAMP stack you'll need to set it up too